# For loop over Array is not working. how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, searchbar

I want to create a searchbar on a website. It should update the content while you are typing. With an if statement it is working. But the for loop causes problems.

```
var shoplist = ["1", "2", "3"];
var shoplistlength

function hid(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  shopsuche = document.getElementById("search").value;

  for (var i = 0; i < shoplistlength; i++) {
    if (shoplist[i].includes(shopsuche)) {
      document.getElementById("2").children[i].style.display = "inline"
    }
  }
}
```

The inputfield:

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                    type="search"
                    placeholder="What you are looking for?"
                    aria-label="Search"
                    name="search"
                    id="search"
                    onkeyup="hid(event)"
                    >
```

I want to minimize the code through the for-loop. I will check each variable in the shoplist and then i will check if the shopsuche contains letters from the list. If yes the site should show a list element. I will get the ul list child with the variable i because the shoplist is build like the list.

Update:

I deleted shoplistLength and replaced it with the number. I know its not the best way but I try to understand my mistake. I think something with my array is wrong. If I do this:

```
 var shoplist = ["1", "2", "3"];
 function hid(event){
 ... 
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     if ("1".includes(shopsuche)) { 
       document.getElementById("2").children[i].style.display="none"}
```

I get the expected result. However, if I use the array and index:

```
if (shoplist[i].includes(shopsuche)) {
```

then the site remains the same.

Comment: `shoplistLength` doesn't have a length set so your for loop doesn't run. You could also write this a little simpler with ES6 as: `shopList.forEach(l => { if (l.includes(shopsuche)) { ... } });`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. But something must be wrong in my code it will not show the results. Maybe it is because of my array. Update in the first post of mine.

Comment: Your code as posted should work, but we can't see your HTML. Maybe you've cut some things out of the JS too. Right before the if statement do `console.log(shoplist[i], shopsuche, shoplist[i].includes(shopsuche))` and then see what's showing in the console. If it matches up the way you think, then you'll know which entries it's getting inside the `if` and then you'll know that something is wrong with your `document.getElementById` logic.

Comment: Also you should always be doing `shoplist.length` (or even better just using `.forEach` like I originally suggested) instead of hardcoding the `i < 3` which you'll forget to change when you get this working, and then will only work for your first three elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jbluehdorn points out, you haven't initiated the shoplistlength.

For cleaner and more readable code, I would suggest using the forEach method when looping through arrays:

```
var shoplist = ["1", "2", "3"]

function hid(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  shopsuche = document.getElementById("search").value

  shoplist.forEach((shop, i) => {
    if (shop.includes(shopsuche)) {
      document.getElementById("2").children[i].style.display = "inline"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're not instantiating `shopListLength` to anything so your loop is saying `for(var i = 0; i < undefined; i++)` which would exit immediately.

Comment: Yes that's why no further execution will happen which are written in a loop

Comment: I deleted shoplistLength and replaced it with the number. I know its not the best way but I try to understand my mistake. I think something with my array is wrong. 

If I do this
`code  var shoplist = ["1", "2", "3"]; 

 
function hid(event){ 
...
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if ("1".includes(shopsuche)) {
        document.getElementById("2").children[i].style.display="none"} `

I get the expected result
If I use the array 

   `code    if (shoplist[i].includes(shopsuche)) {`

The site remains the same